# how to setup google tag manager to work in offline

Tags: google-analytics, progressive-web-apps, google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

we have PWA offline application.I tried using workbox which will work offline to track the google tag events but not working

below are the code which i tried in service work file

```
googleAnalytics.initialize({
 parameterOverrides: {
 cd1: 'offline',
},
});
```

[image]